# Spring data - "class path resource [org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/vendor/MySQLExceptionSorter.class"

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-data

Im trying for days now to setup a simple gradle project with spring data.
here are my configuration files:

Gradle dependencied file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name:'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-beans', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-context', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-core', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-expression', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-web', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
/*compile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring', version:'3.2.0.RELEASE'*/
compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name:'spring-security-core', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'cglib', name:'cglib', version:'2.2'
compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version:'1.1.1'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version:'1.4.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'commons-dbcp', name: 'commons-dbcp', version:'1.4'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version:'3.1.1.RELEASE'
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.6'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-c3p0', version:'4.2.1.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-entitymanager', version:'4.2.1.Final'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version:'1.3.2'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

application-context.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- Add this tag to enable annotations transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />
```

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
            <!-- <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/> -->
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/> -->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:33306/db" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1800" />
    </bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com" />
```

The rest of my project is a simple repository , service and controller.

When i execute the tomcat i get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/D:/workspaceNG/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/spring-mvc-simple-master/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar!/com/mysql/jdbc/integration/jboss/ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter.class]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/vendor/MySQLExceptionSorter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:281)
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getCandidates(RepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:53)
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.parse(RepositoryBeanDefinitionParser.java:69)
... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/vendor/MySQLExceptionSorter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:76)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:324)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:258)
... 33 more
```

Any ideas what is this? Why does jboss got anything to do with my project???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
```

The problem is that you are component-scanning on the `com` package, so basically you are scanning **ALL** the classes. For this scanning to work all the classes need to be loaded and when a class gets loaded into the classloader so are its referenced classes.

In this case the class `ExtendedMysqlExceptionSorter` is loaded (due to your `com` component-scan) and it needs the `MySQLExceptionSorter` from JBoss. Basically not loading the class wills solve your problem.

The solution is not to scan for everything but only scan your own packages. This will also make your application start a lot faster.

Some other remarks regarding your config

1. `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`.
2. `hibernate.connection.*` properties don't do anything because you are injecting a `DataSource`.
3. The `jpaDialect` is already set by `JpaVendorAdapter`.

Removing this will cleanup your configuration.